# Babel - Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, babeljs, file-watcher

We switched from Uglify.js to Babel & Babel minifier, yet while Babel and Babel minifer seem to work fine, using ES6 import/export give me some trouble on the browser page.

I am using WebStorm as an IDE and I use a Babel file watcher to automatically minify the files inside a nested file (inside the original minified file). Am I obliged to use a module bundler such as Webpack to be able to run the code in browser or did I do something wrong in the configure?
[[The file watcher configures & console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lL9X.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwktx.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.